# Kivy - My .exe file on Windows does not open

Tags: python, windows, kivy, exe, pyinstaller

I am trying to create a windows Kivy program but i am facing some problems. I followed the steps outlined here on the kivy website (https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/packaging-windows.html) and i was able to create an executable without any errors. The problem is when i open the executable that is in the dist folder it opens up a terminal/command prompt for a split second then closes immediately. I cant really tell what is wrong as i don't get any errors.

I saved my spec file in the same folder as my python file (main.py), kivy file(chemgui.kv) and an image which i use in my kivy file (chemistrybck.jfif). Here are the steps that i undertook to create my .exe file.

```
python -m PyInstaller --name Chem C:\Users\AdhamAlHossary\Desktop\Package\main.py
```

Chem.spec

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-

from kivy_deps import sdl2, glew

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['C:\\Users\\AdhamAlHossary\\Desktop\\Package\\main.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\AdhamAlHossary\\Desktop\\Package'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)

pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)

exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          [],
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='Chem',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=True )

coll = COLLECT(exe, Tree('C:\\Users\\AdhamAlHossary\\Desktop\\Package\\'),
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               *[Tree(p) for p in (sdl2.dep_bins + glew.dep_bins)],
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               upx_exclude=[],
               name='Chem')
```

Then:

```
python -m PyInstaller Chem.spec
```

I would really appreciate if someone can help me out. I searched online hoping to find a solution but didnt find anything that matches my problem.

I am also using Kivy 1.11.1, Python 3.7 and PyInstaller 3.6.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running the exe from a terminal? I suspect your code works fine, but after execution it closes.

You could use pyautogui and add something like this:

```
import keyboard
#Your script
keyboard.wait('esc')
```

Now it will only close when you press escape.

Comment: Shall i add this code to my main.py file? What is really confusing me is that i tried packaging the same file(touchtracer) that is used in this example (https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/packaging-windows.html) and the same thing happens.

Comment: And yes, i tried running my exe from the terminal and the same thing happened